# Hosting a new spring boot application using a sub domaine

Tags: spring-boot, subdomain, hosting

I am using a domain ex [ cleanword.com ] when i deploy my spring boot application in webapps (ROOT) and it works , I want to host another one for test  using a subdomaine ex [ test.cleanworld.com ], I added the host in my server.xml and it does not work
Here's the content of my server.xml file (see img below) :

[image]